# How to update PHP on opensuse?

Tags: updates, opensuse, php5

How can I update my PHP 5.2.14 to PHP 5.3 on my OpenSuSE 11.1 server using YaST or any other way?

Comment: openSUSE 11.1 is no longer officially supported.  You may want to upgrade the entire system.  Consider placing a notice on your site for planned downtime and use that time to upgrade to 11.4.